# Python: read a large csv file and aggregate/process rows by field

Tags: python, csv

I have in input a potentially large csv file (gzip compressed) with a known structure. I don't know in advance the size of this file, but let's say it can't fit in memory. The rows in this csv are ordered like the following:

```
key1, ...other fields
key1,
key1,
key1,
key2,
key2,
key3,
key4,
key4,
...
```

so basically they are ordered by the value in the first column (let's call it `key`), but it is unknown how many rows are there for each distinct key. Basically I need to scan the whole file and process only the first N rows per each key (could be more than N rows for some of the keys). These N rows per key can be processed in memory.

I came up with this code, but I don't like it very much. It is a bit messy:

```py
import gzip


def process_rows(key rows):    
    print(f'Processed rows for key {key}')


def main(file_path, N=1000):    
    with gzip.GzipFile(filename=file_path) as file:
        curr_key = None
        rows_to_process = []

        for line in file:
            line = line.decode().strip()

            if len(line) == 0:
                continue

            fields = line.split(',')
            [key, field2, field3] = fields

            if curr_key is not None:
                if curr_key != key or (len(rows_to_process) > 0 and len(rows_to_process) % N == 0):                    
                    process_rows(key, rows_to_process)

                    # Find next key if needed
                    while curr_key == key:
                        line = next(file, None)

                        if line is None:
                            return  # End of file, exit

                        line = line.decode().strip()

                        if len(line) < 1:
                            continue

                        fields = line.split(',')
                        [key, field2, field3] = fields

                    print('Found next key', key)

                    # Reset rows to process
                    rows_to_process = []

            curr_key = key
            rows_to_process.append([key, field2, field3])

        # Flush trailing data
        if (len(rows_to_process) > 0):
            process_rows(key, rows_to_process)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: This is probably better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @0x263A thanks I didn't know about this section. I'll try to post there